# When registration is successful, authentication will be ignored for urls that require authentication

Tags: spring-security

This is the config code when I want to enter the /order page and it is required to authenticate (/login). I want to expand the problem when I successfully register a user, when I go to /order, there is no need to authenticate through the login form anymore.

```
package r2s.com.configs;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    };

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login","/register/**","/URLToReachResourcesFolder/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/order").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/save_login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/loginSuccess")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll();
    }

}
```

This is code register

```
package r2s.com.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import r2s.com.dto.CustomerDTO;
import r2s.com.models.CustomerEntity;
import r2s.com.service.CustomerService;

@Controller
public class RegisterController {
    
    @Autowired
    CustomerService customerService;
    
    
    @RequestMapping("/register")
    String register(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
        String referer = request.getHeader("Referer");
        session.setAttribute("redirectUrl", referer);
        return "Register";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/register/save")
    String saveRegister(@ModelAttribute("newCustomer") CustomerDTO customerDTO,HttpSession session) {
        CustomerEntity customerEntity = new CustomerEntity();
        CustomerDTO customerDTO2 = new CustomerDTO();
        customerEntity = customerDTO2.convertCustomerEntity(customerDTO);
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bcrypt = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String encryptedPwd = bcrypt.encode(customerEntity.getPassword());
        customerEntity.setPassword(encryptedPwd);
        customerEntity = customerService.save(customerEntity);
        session.setAttribute("customer", customerEntity);
        String redirectUrl = (String) session.getAttribute("redirectUrl");
        session.removeAttribute("redirectUrl");
        if (redirectUrl != null && !redirectUrl.isEmpty()) {
            return "redirect:" + redirectUrl;
        } else {
            return "redirect:/";
        }
    }
}
```

I want when the registration is successful, when I go to /order, I don't have to login to authenticate anymore